# Get dateinput max and min date

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-tools

I'm using `dateinput()` from the [jQuery TOOLS UI library](http://jquerytools.org/demos/dateinput/customize.html), and I set min and max dates.

However, I want to get those values after setting them. How can achieve this?

Comment: `dateinput` is not a standard plugin. Can you please give more details on exactly what you're using.

Comment: there is date picker called dateinput(), just like datepicker() in jquery, for more information see http://jquerytools.org/demos/dateinput/customize.html

Comment: The documentation on the site and on GitHub is seriously lacking... I would suggest to inspect the jQuery object in your browser console and try to find it there.

Comment: there is method called getConf(), but I'm not sure how to use it.
check this http://jquerytools.org/documentation/dateinput/

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$(":date").dateinput({
    format: 'dddd dd, mmmm yyyy', // the format displayed for the user
    selectors: true, // whether month/year dropdowns are shown
    min: -100, // min selectable day (100 days backwards)
    max: 100, // max selectable day (100 days onwards)
    offset: [10, 20], // tweak the position of the calendar
    speed: 'fast', // calendar reveal speed
    firstDay: 1, // which day starts a week. 0 = sunday, 1 = monday etc..
    change: function (a) {
        console.log($(this)[0].getConf().min);//min value
        console.log($(this)[0].getConf().max);//max value
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<input type="date" name="date1" value="Today" />
<input type="date" name="date2" value="10 days from now" min="2010-03-01" max="2012-01-01" class="one" />
<input type="date" name="date3" value="15" min="-25" max="25" data-value="15" />
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/GCu2D/159/

Apart from `change` function, it also has `onShow` and `onHide` just in case if you want to use min max later or on show.